# Manipulating FedEx label in vb.net API

Tags: vb.net, api, pdf, fedex

I am writing a FedEx API in vb.net to work with our universe database.  So far everything is about done but i'm stuck on the printing label part.  The code FedEx gave me saves the label image as a pdf and prints from acrobat.  Problem is you can't really do anything with a pdf image, or so i'm sure of at least, meaning i can't line the image up correctly on a 4 x 6 thermal label.  How would i do this or is there a good way to just use the image and assign x and y coordinates without messing up the FedEx label?  here is the code from where it saves the label down to print:

```
Sub ShowShipmentLabels(ByRef CompletedShipmentDetail As CompletedShipmentDetail, ByRef packageDetail As CompletedPackageDetail, ByVal isCodShipment As Boolean)
        If (packageDetail.Label.Parts(0).Image IsNot Nothing) Then
            ' Save outbound shipping label
            Dim FileName As String = getProperty("labelpath") + packageDetail.TrackingIds(0).TrackingNumber + ".pdf"

            SaveLabel(FileName, packageDetail.Label.Parts(0).Image)
            Mylabel.Print()

            ' Save COD Return label
            If (isCodShipment) Then
                FileName = getProperty("labelpath") + CompletedShipmentDetail.CompletedPackageDetails(0).TrackingIds(0).TrackingNumber + "CR.pdf"
                SaveLabel(FileName, CompletedShipmentDetail.CompletedPackageDetails(0).CodReturnDetail.Label.Parts(0).Image)
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
Sub SaveLabel(ByRef labelFileName As String, ByRef labelBuffer() As Byte)
        ' Save label buffer to file
        Dim LabelFile As FileStream = New FileStream(labelFileName, FileMode.Create)
        LabelFile.Write(labelBuffer, 0, labelBuffer.Length)
        LabelFile.Close()
        ' Display label in Acrobat
        DisplayLabel(labelFileName)
    End Sub

    Sub DisplayLabel(ByRef labelFileName As String)
        Dim info As System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo = New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(labelFileName)
        info.UseShellExecute = True
        info.CreateNoWindow = True
        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        info.Verb = "Print"
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info)
    End Sub
```

Comment: I assume, then, that you are not using label printers such as Zebra printers, but instead are using something more like an office laser jet to print? If so, the advice Van Amburg gives in the answer below is good advice. The FedEx API gives you a few options for retrieving the label, such as PDF, getting the ZPL code, PNG, etc. It may be more advantageous to get the label in a different format rather than PDF, something more "editable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it looks fine on the screen, but is not aligning correctly on the printer then you should probably look to the printer settings either on the device itself or in the driver. I would with the driver, you probably need to specificy the media and maybe adjust the margins.

Answer (score 0):

Chris, if this hasn't been solved yet, check out this FAQ from our database at [Shippo](https://goshippo.com): http://support.goshippo.com/hc/en-us/articles/203804319-My-labels-are-not-printing-correctly-How-can-I-fix-this-

Printing 4x6 can be a bit of a headache at first. If it's not yet working for you, feel free to comment with more details what printer you use and your printer settings. This would help to debug further.

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to save the image in ZPLII format. Do it and save it as `tracking_id.zpl`.

Share the Zebra printer as FedexThermal.

Then create a print.cmd script on he fly from vb to execute...

```
COPY /B tracking_id.zpl \\localhost\FedexThermal
```

Then in vb create a process to run that script,

Works for me.